# Gtk version problem while installing themes to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, themes, gtk, customization

I am a little confused with the gtk stuff. I heard Ubuntu 12.10 already has *gtk3.6.0*. I am trying to install a theme that says it requires gtk 3.6.0. So when I click download, it doesn't download, nothing happens.

Themes in *gtk2* download just fine though, and when using the terminal to check what version of *gtk3* I have, it says I have none.

**What do I need to do to either install *gtk3*, or enable it so I can run any themes from gnome-look?**

Comment: "So when I click download, it doesn't download, nothing happens" -This has nothing to do with GTK, Ubuntu or Gnome. Use another browser.

Comment: @UriHerrera It might reflect a systemwide problem. But even if it's a browser issue, that's still on-topic here. You might want to post a slightly expanded version of your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ruled it out being a web browser issue from the start, tried 2 web browsers. It was simple. The themes didn't work. Also have to run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/gtk3`. Seemed to have fixed my problem. Best [document to get a custom gtk3 theme running on Ubuntu 12.10](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/11/install-15-best-ubuntu-1210-themes-for.html). I found a few others, but this one break it down as simple as it gets. You don't even have to move the themes files any where with these steps. I have to admit, I was starting to hate this OS but seems like everything on this OS is actually pretty easy, just need to find the right steps. At this point I have everything set up and starting on the fun stuff, setting up *lamp* and figuring out how to use all that. Anyone have any pointers on setting up *Python*?